# Writing a function in terms of its power series with some tricky reindexing steps

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Represent the following function as a power series and find it's radius of convergence:

$$\frac{x^2}{(8+x)^3}$$

---

By [Using differentiation to find the power series of a fairly tricky function!!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877312/using-differentiation-to-find-the-power-series-of-a-fairly-tricky-function) We know that

$\frac{1}{(8+x)^3} = \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+2} (n+2)(n+1) x^n (\frac{1}{8})^{n+3})$

Therefore we have:

$\frac{x^2}{(8+x)^3} = x^2 (\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+2} (n+2)(n+1) x^n (\frac{1}{8})^{n+3})$

Multiplying the $x^2$ through yields

$= \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+2} (n+2)(n+1) x^{n+2} (\frac{1}{8})^{n+3})$

But we can't have a power series be expressed in terms of $x^{n+2}$. It needs to be in terms of $x^n$. So we subtract a $2$ from everywhere an $n$ appears in our expressoin and make the summation start at $n=2$

$= \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n} (n)(n-1) x^{n} (\frac{1}{8})^{n+1})$

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Solution verification tag

Comment: Looks all okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's correct. Since for $n=0$ and $n=1$ the terms vanish, if you want to start at $n=0$ we can write $$\frac{x^2}{(x+3)^3}= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n} (n)(n-1) x^{n} (\frac{1}{8})^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n)(n-1)x^n(\frac{1}{8})^{n+1}$$

Comment: Eh, solution manual had it starting at $n=2$, so I just went with that

Comment: Yeah that's fine, I said that you can start at $n=0$ because your previous sum: $\frac{1}{8+x^2}$ started at $n=0$.